# Symfony Get Logged in User in Error File

Tags: symfony, session

I am using Symfony for developing my project.

I am using production mode for testing my site.

When i have logged in with my user i got correct user in header but when something went wrong my error.html page appear and at that time i didn't get my logged in user with `{{app.user}}`.

So it looks like no one is logged in to the system for that page only.

I want to disply logged in user on my header.

Images are below.

[image]

404 page where i can not get my logged in user.

[image]

Can anyone help me with this.

Thank You.

Comment: Has, maybe, this page another firewall and you're not logged against this?

Answer (score 0):

When an exception is thrown, the exception is caught forwarded to another controller. 
If you need to pass additional informations to your error page you should override the default ExceptionController:

```
use Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\Controller\ExceptionController;

class CustomExceptionController extends ExceptionController {
    //override Action or Template method and pass the information about logged in user
}
```

Eventually, tell symfony which ExceptionController should use:

```
parameters:
    twig.controller.exception.class: YourBundle\Controller\CustomExceptionController
```

Comment: Hello Srdjan, Thank You but i do not know which action i need to override.

Comment: Then you still can't access the user in this controller ... I injected the TokenStorageInterface, but still there is no user shown. How to solve this?

Comment: @MathiasBader Which version of Symfony?

Comment: @Srdjan Symfony version 3.4

Comment: Did you try to configure a service to pass the Twig environment and the debug flag to the constructor as mentioned in documentation? http://symfony.com/doc/3.4/controller/error_pages.html#custom-exception-controller